# why is this css gradient acting weird?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

newbie here. im trying to put the gradient in the whole  element. it actually works and all that but the gradient just looks weird when I try to put in these shades...[here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1SJH.jpg) the screenshot for what I'm talking about. i tried to search for the solutions but I cant seem to find any. are gradients supposed to act like this? like I mean with all those repeated rectangles and all..? and the rectangles there appear even harder (in color and all) when i try to rotate the gradient. yikes.

Comment: don't post screenshot, put in the actual code here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So basically you are not adjusting the size and the background is repeating.Try using this Code below

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg,white,black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 768px 1024px;
```